# Change order of new file menu items Eclipse rcp

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am implementing now RCP
application and I need to add custom menu item to File -> New submenu and I did that by two ways

- By plugin.xml using

> menuContribution locationURI="menu:new?after=new"

- By Implaemanting ContributionFactory in Java code

My Problem is that I can't insert the menu item insert the additions also after the project item or after package item. I tried to get the locationURI
of the inner item by the plugin menu spy but could only this result get "
menu:new?after=additions" and I tried in the java code but I need to get the list of items of new file menu but I get only this useless interface IContributionRoot any solution in XML or in java code without using application adviser?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only supported way to add to the File > New menu is by defining a 'New Wizard' using the `org.eclipse.ui.newWizards` extension point. Your new wizard will appear in the 'Other' part of the menu.

You can make your wizard also appear in the top part of the menu for a particular perspective by using the `org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions` extension point to add a `newWizardShortcut`. You may need to reset the perspective or customize the perspective to get this to work.

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions"> 
    <perspectiveExtension 
        targetID="org.eclipse.ui.resourcePerspective"> 
        <newWizardShortcut id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards.NewProjectCreationWizard"/> 
    </perspectiveExtension> 
</extension>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment but actually I need this for customer requirement and i have already did exactly what you said but they want to locat the items in this postion exactly

Comment: Any idee how to create that

Comment: You can't position things exactly. The new menu manager will not allow it

Comment: I have the problem solved by remove the old NewWizardMenu item from new submenu in my ContributionFactory and create my own and add the custom item in addItems(List list) method Cheers!!!